# Can I reuse a JLabel component on the different parts of my program?

Tags: java, swing, calendar, jlabel

For example, I have a calendar. Is it possible to reuse the JLabel that contains the date number "1" to all the months in my calendar? or do I have to make another JLabel in all of it? I did a full year calendar but my code has 7k lines of code...

Comment: 7K lines of code seems a little excessive. Don't tell me you're copy pasting day-by-day...

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys! The JLabel uses texts. I also use JPanels for each month of the year. So there are a bunch of JLabels in my panels, making me lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: yes you *could* reuse a GUI component, but then the prior component would be unusable since the JLabel can be displayed on only one container at a time, the container that it was most recently added to.

But why would you want to? Re-use an ImageIcon if your JLabel is displaying it. Otherwise you're just displaying text with it. Your question suggests that your program's design could be off, that you might want to re-think the structure of your program. Most importantly, don't confuse your program's model with it's view.

---

Your recent comments:'

> Would it be possible if I don't use an ImageIcon? and just use pure JLabel text? I am using the Netbeans GUI creator btw.

Again **why would you want to**? It just holds text. I advise you not to do this, and again I fear that your program design is bad. Maybe what you really want to use is a JTable.

> Hi! thanks for the fast reply! My JLabel dates are within a JPanel (month panels), and all the panels are within a JFrame. And when I click a JButton, it hides the current panel and shows the next one. Each Panel(12month panels) has many JLabels. Should I make another JFrame for each year to avoid lags?

There should be no lag. You will want to swap JPanels by using a CardLayout.

What you likely want to do is create a class for a general Month object and then create instances of this object for each specific month. Again, think re-design. Also, learn to code without generated code since this will enhance your understanding of the library that you're using.

---

## **Edit**  More Recommendations:

First create a non-GUI model class, Month:

- Give it a String field for the month name
- Give it a day of the week (possibly an enum) for the day of the week of the 1st of this month
- Give it an int field for number of days of the week.
- You might want to give it ArrayList of DayEvent objects to hold possible events to put on the calendar such as birthdays, holidays, etc. as well as setter and getter methods for this.

Then for your GUI portion, create a GUI class to represent the month, say called MonthView

- Create it by ***hand*** not by NetBeans generated code
- Give it a Month field so it can hold and use its model, an instance of the Month class above.
- Give it a BorderLayout
- Give it a title JLabel that displays the Month name, and add this BorderLayout.NORTH.
- Give it a JPanel that uses a GridLayout(0, 7) -- for seven columns, and a variable number of rows. Add this BorderLayout.CENTER
- Populate this GridLayout with JLabels.
- Have logic available that will place your date strings in the correct JLabel grid cells.

Now your dates will be represented by code that has at most 35 JLabels. Sure there will be 365 JLabels for your dates made, but there will only need to be *code* for 35 (7 * 5) JLabels to allow you to create all your JLabels.

Comment: Would it be possible if I don't use an ImageIcon? and just use pure JLabel text? I am using the Netbeans GUI creator btw.

Comment: Hi. My program gui looks like this:
http://s16.postimg.org/w41b329ud/asdasdad.png

Can I recreate it using JTable? really thanks for the answers.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth advices. I lag in the coding section as there are tons of JLabels in the source code. Also, the JLables have their own set of parameters like setLocation. I am using a CardLayout by the way. There are no lags in the program itself. Now my problem is how do I display the dates without populating the source code with billions of JLabels. Sorry for too many questions. I am fairly new to programming and the lack of time to learn deeper :/

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new JLabel if you're going to draw it concurrently with earlier JLabels.

To get a high quality answer, you should provide a clear, simple, self contained code example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the fast reply! My JLabel dates are within a JPanel (month panels), and all the panels are within a JFrame. And when I click a JButton, it hides the current panel and shows the next one. Each Panel(12month panels) has many JLabels. Should I make another JFrame for each year to avoid lags?

Comment: You probably shouldn't make new JFrames, as that's the top level container which holds components. You could create a separate JPanel for each calendar month, and lazy load it so that only the ones that are visible have been initialized.